# Import VB6 MSFlexgrid contents

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, vb6, copy

I have a C# .NET Windows Form Application which contains a DataGridView control. 
I would like it to `import/copy` the contents of another grid control which resides in another application which is written in VB6.

Is this possible ?

Can I extract the information from a grid control in a third party application into my own?

Any help or code samples would be appreciated.

Cheers Jonathon

Comment: Does your 3rd party application have an import mechanism?

Comment: Do you have the access to the VB6 Code?? can u change If required to do ?

Comment: No, the 3rd party application does not have an import mechanism. And no, I do not have access to the third party application source code.